# Pdf.worker.min.js I am trying to use this library in my chrome extension but I have a error inside the library file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

i use this library in my **chrome extension** to work with pdf files and while migrating my extension from **manifest v2 to v3** I ran in to some problems the in the **pdf.worker.min.js** a certain block of code has been problematic when i removed it everything seems to work fine but i am not sure if it is the right move to remove it the code is in the createDocumentHandler function what i did is i commented the condition as you can see in the code snippet bellow here is the block of code :
is anyone has an explanation why this error happened ? and what can i change to fix it

````
    for (const property in []) {
      enumerableProperties.push(property);
    }

    // if (enumerableProperties.length) {
    //   throw new Error("The `Array.prototype` contains unexpected enumerable properties: " + enumerableProperties.join(", ") + "; thus breaking e.g. `for...in` iteration of `Array`s.");
    // }```
````

Comment: Do you modify `Array.prototype` in your code?

Comment: no i havent modified the file at all